# How to use nn.CrossEntropyLoss() for a PatchGAN Discriminator output?

Tags: pytorch, google-colaboratory, loss-function, cross-entropy

I am trying to use the `nn.CrossEntropyLoss()` to find the cross-entropy loss between reals and fakes of a patchGAN discriminator that outputs a tensor of shape `(batch_size, 1, 30, 30)`.

I am confused with the documentation [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html) that asks for class indexes instead of targets.

```
CE_loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
real_loss = CE_loss(discriminator_real_outputs, torch.ones_like(discriminator_real_outputs))
fake_loss= CE_loss(discriminator_fake_outputs, torch.zeros_like(discriminator_fake_outputs))
```

I understand from an error that the target requires `long int`. I converted it to long.

```
CE_loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
real_loss = CE_loss(discriminator_real_outputs, torch.ones_like(discriminator_real_outputs).long())
fake_loss= CE_loss(discriminator_fake_outputs, torch.zeros_like(discriminator_fake_outputs).long())
```

Then it asked for the target to be of the `(batch_size, 30,30)` instead of `(batch_size, 1,30,30)`, fixed that too.

After that, it returned this error `cuda runtime error (710) device-side assert triggered` which broke the GPU on Google Colab and couldn't run it again until I reset the runtime.

I want to use this loss like other losses in the form
`loss = Loss(input, target)` without the index. How do I go about this?

Comment: Try using `BCELoss` or `BCELossWithLogits` (if your model doesn't have sigmoid at the last layer). Probably softmax on a single channel is not the same as sigmoid (and CE loss of PyTorch uses softmax internally) which may be giving the "device-side assert triggered" error.

Comment: The discriminator model does have sigmoid at the last layer.

Comment: Why did pytorch make the CrossEntropy Function this way? I do not understand how it should make things easier.

Comment: CrossEntropyLoss is usually used for multi-class while BCE ones are for binary classification. Also, the reason for PyTorch to have sigmoid or softmax within the loss function is to utilize some mathematical tricks that improve the stability of the computations.

Comment: How do we use the multi-class functionality for a 2D RGB image that went through a patch GAN discriminator? Can you help me with understanding how to implement that function and why and what index is needed as arguments?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're implementing. Do you want a real/fake discriminator or a multi-class discriminator? If it's a real/fake disc. then go for `BCE` ones, else go for `CE`. For CE, you need to give the actual class label (ranging from 0 to C) and not one-hot representation for the label and the predictions of your model for the other input.

Comment: Can you please explain the class labels with respect to a 2D image? What is C in 0 to C? and why does it need long int? Would be grateful if you could help me with understanding what is happing inside `nn.CrossEntropyLoss()`. Thank You.

Comment: C is the number of classes (but it would be 0 to `C-1` to be precise). So, for a 2D image, you have to classify every pixel i.e. every pixel will have a C-dimensional vector prediction (if you combine them, it will be of shape CxHxW). Corresponding to this prediction, you should have a HxW matrix with the labels in range 0 to `C-1`. Inside the CELoss, PyTorch will convert the HxW matrix to one-hot and apply softmax to the CxHxW prediction tensor. After that, it will compute the CE in the usual way (-label * log(pred)).